# link_to path definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developoing a **Rails v2.3.2** app.

I have a controller:

```
class SchoolController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def edit
    @school=School.find_by_id params[:id]

  end

  def check_teachers
    @teachers = @school.teachers
    ...
  end

end
```

in `app/views/schools/edit.html.erb` I would like to have a `link`, click on it will trigger the `check_teachers` method in the **controller**, how to define the **path** for this `link`?

app/views/schools/edit.html.erb :

```
link_to 'Check teachers' WHAT_IS_THE_PATH_HERE
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
link_to 'Check teachers', :action => :check_teachers, :id => @school.id
```

or

```
link_to 'Check teachers', "/school/check_teachers/#{@school.id}"
```

or you can define a named-route in `config/routes.rb` like this:

```
map.check_teachers, '/school/check_teachers/:id' :controller => :school, :action => :check_teachers
```

and call the url-helper generated by the named-route like this:

```
link_to 'Check teachers', check_teachers_path(:id => @school.id)
```

and you can use this id to find teachers in the controller

```
def check_teachers
  @school = School.find params[:id]
  @teachers = @school.teachers
  ...
end
```

Comment: howd you get the `check_teachers_path` url? Is there a way to check what urls are available or is this a specific naming format? Thanks!

Comment: `rake routes` will give you both the URL and the url helper if it is available.

Comment: you mean the `Prefix` column? So in this case I should see `check_teachers ` right? And all I need to do is append a `_path` to it?

Comment: Yes. If you append `_path` you will get relative URL like `/school/check_teachers` and if you append `_url` you will get absolute URL like ` http://local host:3000/school/check_teachers` depending on the rails environment and the host specified in the config files.

Comment: should be ```link_to 'Check teachers', "/school/check_teachers/#{@school.id}"``` (with double quote) since string interpolation is used?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will fix that in the answer. Nice catch 

Answer (score 2):

You can define something like this in your `routes.rb` file.

```
map.connect "schools/:id/check_teachers", :controller => "schools", :action => "check_teachers"
```

You'd then set up your `link_to` as follows:

```
link_to "Check teachers", check_teachers_path(:id => @school.id)
```

You'll need to add this bit of code into the controller, as model states aren't shared between controller actions:

```
 def check_teachers
    @school = School.find_by_id(params[:id])
    # Then you can access the teachers with @school.teachers
  end
```

This is untested but should work. Just comment if you have any further issues.